# Couchdb query multiple keys get all docs by one of keys

Tags: python, couchdb

I have a view in couchdb that returns results with two keys:

```
[<string_key>, <date>]
```

I need to ignore second key "date" and return all docs that matches key "string". But when I'm trying ignore the "date" key, view returns all values. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use startkey and endkey for doing this. You can ignore the second parameter by using {} in the end key. It returns all the possible results.

For reference you can look at the summary of this article:  http://ryankirkman.com/2011/03/30/advanced-filtering-with-couchdb-views.html